# How get value in query before initialize list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hello i'm just starting with MVC i Entity Framework and i have problem.
Can i get value of my Val4 in query?
I think i waste time initialize my list twice.

```
var query = from p in db.Table1
            join s in db.Table2 on p.ID equals s.sID
            join m in db.Table3 on s.sID equals m.ID
            group s by p into G
            select new Row
            {
                Val1 = G.Key,
                Val2 = G.Sum(x => x.someVal),
                Val3 = (from Z in db.Table4
                                 join p in db.Table5 on Z.ID equals p.ZamowienieID
                                 select p.otherVal).ToList().DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(),
                Val4 = 0,
            };

var list = query.ToList();

list.ForEach(x => x.Val4 = ((decimal)x.Val3 / (x.Val2 + (decimal)x.Val3)) * 100});

list = list.OrderbY(x =>x.Val4).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but not directly in the `Row` initializer.

In order to be able to reuse `Val3` and `Val3` in both `Val4` and projection. if you were using LINQ method syntax, you would use intermediate anonymous projection (`Select`). In query syntax you can use [`let`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause) expressions for the same purpose:

```
var query = from p in db.Table1
            join s in db.Table2 on p.ID equals s.sID
            join m in db.Table3 on s.sID equals m.ID
            group s by p into G
            let Val2 = G.Sum(x => x.someVal)
            let Val3 = (from Z in db.Table4
                        join p in db.Table5 on Z.ID equals p.ZamowienieID
                        select p.otherVal).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()
            let Val4 = ((decimal)x.Val3 / (x.Val2 + (decimal)x.Val3)) * 100
            orderby Val4
            select new Row
            {
                Val1 = G.Key,
                Val2 = Val2,
                Val3 = Val3,
                Val4 = Val4,
            };
```

Answer (score 5):

It could be better to use `getter` of the `Val4` property.

```
public class Row
{
    public int Val1 { get; set; }

    public int Val2 { get; set; }

    public int Val3 { get; set; }

    public decimal Val4
    {
        get
        {
            return (decimal)Val3 / (Val2 + (decimal)Val3) *100;
        }
    }
}
```

And the query looks like;

```
var query = from p in db.Table1
            join s in db.Table2 on p.ID equals s.sID
            join m in db.Table3 on s.sID equals m.ID
            group s by p into G
            select new Row
            {
                Val1 = G.Key,
                Val2 = G.Sum(x => x.someVal),
                Val3 = (from Z in db.Table4
                                 join p in db.Table5 on Z.ID equals p.ZamowienieID
                                 select p.otherVal).ToList().DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()
            };
var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I was thinking the same, but then `OrderBy` should happen in memory, e.g. `var result = query.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Val4).ToList();`